# SpringBatch - How to track whether Update is happening successfully or not

Tags: spring-batch

I have 2 ItemWriters, one for DB Insert and one for DB Update.

With use of ClassifierCustomItemWriter which I am calling the respective ItemWriter  for new record and update the existing records.

Here i have concern. How to know the update has been happened or not ? For Example, if the "Application ID" not exists in the DB , the ItemWriter will not throw any error, but i want to know that update has not happened for this record and log it.

How can i track that ?

```
@Bean
    public ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<TRSBatchEntryFormRequest> classifierCompositeItemWriter(ItemWriter<TRSBatchEntryFormRequest> databaseTableItemWriter, ItemWriter<TRSBatchEntryFormRequest> databaseTableUpdateItemWriter) {
        ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<TRSBatchEntryFormRequest> classifierCompositeItemWriter = new ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<>();
        classifierCompositeItemWriter.setClassifier((Classifier<TRSBatchEntryFormRequest, ItemWriter<? super TRSBatchEntryFormRequest>>) trsBatchEntryFormRequest -> {
            if (trsBatchEntryFormRequest.getForm_status().equals("New")) {

                return databaseTableItemWriter;
            } else {

                return databaseTableUpdateItemWriter;
            }
        });
        return classifierCompositeItemWriter;
    }


 // Writer for DB
    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<TRSBatchEntryFormRequest> databaseTableItemWriter(DataSource springBatchDatasource) {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<TRSBatchEntryFormRequest> databaseItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<TRSBatchEntryFormRequest>();
        databaseItemWriter.setDataSource(springBatchDatasource);
        logger.info("INSERT QUERY....:  " + QUERY_INSERT_TRSEntryForms);
        databaseItemWriter.setSql(QUERY_INSERT_TRSEntryForms);
        databaseItemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new TRSDBInputProvider());
        return databaseItemWriter;
    }

    //Update Writer for DB
    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<TRSBatchEntryFormRequest> databaseTableUpdateItemWriter(DataSource springBatchDatasource) {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<TRSBatchEntryFormRequest> databaseItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<TRSBatchEntryFormRequest>();
        databaseItemWriter.setDataSource(springBatchDatasource);
        logger.info("UPDATE QUERY....:  " + QUERY_UPDATE_TRSEntryForms);
        databaseItemWriter.setSql(QUERY_UPDATE_TRSEntryForms);
        databaseItemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new TRSDBInputProvider());
        return databaseItemWriter;
    }
```

​
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't track that with a `CompositeItemWriter`. What you can do is use a custom item writer like the following:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class TRSBatchEntryFormRequestItemWriter implements ItemWriter<TRSBatchEntryFormRequest> {

    private static final String INSERT_ITEM = "insert into item...";
    private static final String UPDATE_ITEM = "update item set...";

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public TRSBatchEntryFormRequestItemWriter(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends TRSBatchEntryFormRequest> items) throws Exception {
        for (TRSBatchEntryFormRequest item : items) {
            int updated = jdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_ITEM);
            if (updated == 0) {
                jdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_ITEM);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to try to issue an update. If the operation returns 0, this means no rows have been updated and the item does not exist in the database, and you can issue an insert in that case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am trying to implement the way you suggested. Will update the proceedings.